# Reparametrizing a regular curve by arclength - what is the relationship between the parameters?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In my differential geometry lecture I saw the following:

> If $\alpha:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a regular curve, there is a reparametrization by arclength $\bar{\alpha}:(\bar{a}, \bar{b}) \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $\bar{\alpha}(s)=\alpha(\varphi(s))$, where $s:(a, b) \to (\bar{a}, \bar{b})$, $\displaystyle s(t)=\int_{t_0}^t ||\alpha'(u)||du, \varphi=s^{-1}.$

I understand how to prove this, but I am a bit confused about the relation between $t$ and $s$. Here is my understanding: even though $s$ is a function, we are going to treat it as an usual variable, so we can differentiate with respect to it and all that (without worrying about $t$, we are just going to use the usual differentiation rules). However, we may also write the equality $\bar{\alpha}(s)=\alpha(\varphi(s))$ in full detail, that is $\bar{\alpha}(s(t))=\alpha(\varphi(s(t)))$, and this may be differentiated with respect to $t$, giving us $\bar{\alpha}'(s(t))||\alpha'(t)||=\alpha'(\varphi(s(t)))\varphi'(s(t))||\alpha'(t)||$, which is equivalent to $\bar{\alpha}'(s(t))=\alpha'(t)\varphi'(s(t))$ by using that the curve is regular and $\varphi=s^{-1}$.

Is what I wrote above correct? I do realize that this is probably just some simple calculus, but I want to make sure that I properly understand this and I am not just handwaving some equalities.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not sure that I understand what you mean, by $s^{-1}$ I wanted to denote the inverse function of $s$ with respect to composition. I hope I didn't make any blunders and wrote $s'(t)=1/||\alpha'(t)||$ somewhere, but I will check.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hm, I don't know, to me it looks correct. Also, I think that maybe you wanted to say that $\varphi'(s(t))=1/||\alpha'(t)||$ because $s'(t)=||\alpha'(t)||$?

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. I didn’t pay enough attention. I apologize.

Comment: @TedShifrin no problem, the actual computations are pretty boring (even though I also have to get those right), I am more interested in the thinking involved. So, am I correct in saying that basically I am going to "forget" that $s$ is a function of $t$ and just differentiate to $s$ normally (i.e., treat it just like any other variable and do whatever I want to do with it) if I want to, but I may also "remember" that this $s$ depends on $t$ and also differentiate wrt to $t$ like I did? This feels a bit odd to me because if I differentiate wrt $s$ I am tempted to apply the chain rule.

Comment: This is what you always do when you introduce a convenient change of variable and use the chain rule! ;)

Comment: @TedShifrin ah, I see. Now I realize that my temptation of using the chain rule is basically what I did in my post, I do realize now that I can as well just treat $s$ as a variable. Thank you very much for your help, I have just started learning differential geometry and I am trying to make sure that I actually get the basics right, I do realize now that my question was a rather easy calculus exercise.